# Android xdebug phpstorm

Tags: php, android, mamp, xdebug

I got xdebug, mamp, and php storm to work well together, now when I visit the url on my machine ex localhost:8888/index.php php storm hits a breakpoint and all is well!

Now when I submit a post request from an android application to index.php I hoped php storm would hit the breakpoint again but it doesnt :/ .. I thought once the debugger was successfully configured that it would debug all incoming connections. guess not.

What do I need to install to make php storm pickup android post requests ?

I am using android studio.

php.ini looks like

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.2/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
```

And again it works fine for web! Just not sure what to do to make it support android or any other connection for that matter..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably missing the GET/POST parameters in your requests.

You have a few options:

1. Use the **xdebug_break()** method in your php code wherever you want to break
2. From the app, append **?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=session_name** to all your server requests.
3. Use the remote_autostart directive (pretty intensive) You could place it in a .htacces like:
   **php_value xdebug.remote_autostart 1** or in php.ini. More details [here](http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_autostart)